# ASP -> SQL incrementing values

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

I have an ASP script to insert into the SQL database, where the value `MIDX` needs to be incremented by one for each entry. (This is for clans in a game.)
There is a column IDX which is a reference to the clan itself and each member added increments the MIDX.

Now in ASPX I had it working fine by finding the MAX(IDX/MIDX) value then doing `MIDX = MIDX + 1`, but it's not working in the asp script -- see below.

```
dim iMIDX

QUERY = "SELECT MAX(MIDX) FROM UL Where ClanName='" & clName & "'"
RS.Open QUERY, ObjConn, 3, 1
If MIDX > 0 Then
    iMIDX = Cint(RS("MIDX").Value)
End If

RS.Close

iMIDX = iMIDX + 1 

QUERY = "INSERT INTO UL ([IDX],[MIDX],[userid],[ChName],[ClanName],[ChType]," _
    & "[ChLv],[Permi],[JoinDate],[DelActive],[PFlag],[KFlag],[MIconCnt]) " _
    & "values('" & IDX & "','" & iMIDX & "','" & clwonUserid & "','" & clwon _
    & "','" & clName & "','" & chtype & "','" & chlv & "','0',getdate(),'0','0','0','0')"
RS.Open QUERY, objConn, 3, 1
End If
```

Comment: Where are you getting the value for `MIDX` in  `If MIDX > 0 Then`

Comment: the MIDX is the value column in the sql table. 
it should increment with each clan member (it starts at 3 with the clan creation (idx is the clan identifier, ie clan 1 is idx 3 clan master midx 3, subsequent clan members idx 3 midx 4,5,6,7, etc) 
i tried a few variants of that, removed the if all together and made the iMIDX = MIDX + 1 it still made the value 1 for each of them, should have been incrementing each and every one, but it enters every single one as 1 :/

Comment: the value for the IF is coming from the SELECT MAX(MIDX), sorry misread your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the value first, it won't appear as a variable.

```
QUERY = "SELECT MAX(MIDX) FROM UL Where ClanName='" & clName & "'"
RS.Open QUERY, ObjConn, 3, 1
iMIDX = 0
If Not(RS.EOF) Then
    iMIDX = Cint(RS(0).Value)
End If
RS.Close
iMIDX = iMIDX + 1
```

The problem with your code was that `iMIDX` was always 0, hence the If condition was never True. Even if it was, you would have gotten error since you don't have any field named "MIDX" in the recordset because you didn't use alias. Luckily, you can also read the field by index.

Comment: Ah k, I'll give it a try, how come it worked in the claninsert aspx script that way then? I had just used the dim iMIDX the the query string seen. 

I am using the select max(MIDX) to pull from the sql the highest instance of the MIDX value seen in the table. that should have retrieved the numerical value of the midx instance no?

Comment: @CraigB no. You probably used some kind of library in your ASP.NET code, in plain C# or VB.NET you won't get anything back as a variable too, but rather will have to read manually from SqlDbDataReader instance, same way you read now in classic ASP from a recordset.

Comment: ah k, so whats it doing with the MIDX value that it is pulling from the SQL database?

Comment: @CraigB taking it from the recordset object, if there are any records, and putting into a local variable, while before that  initializing that variable to 0. :)

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks a lot. 
For my understanding, could you explain the function there? it has me a bit confused,
So the query is pulling the max value for midx
you have created the var of imidx and given it a numerical value  with imidx = 0, 

Then what is happening with the if not RS.EOF ?

Comment: I guess the missing part for you is the "MAX(MIDX)"  in the query becoming a field in the recordset - then you  have to read that field. However, suppose the query returns no results. In such case, you'll have nothing to read and get an error if trying to read anyway. So in classic ASP, the way to ask "Do I have any records in the recordset?" is by checking the EOF (End Of File) property of the recordset. If that property returns True, it means there is no record and you should not read from the recordset. By having the Not, it means the condition will be met when the property returns False.